# Exception in Automapping and FNH in BuildSessionFactory Line

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

i am using the latest version of automapping and FNH with vs2008, i got this exception 
"***Tried to add property 'Description' when already added***"

first , the exception is not informative! i cannot find out which class cause this error.

secondly, how can i solve this problem ? is it because of an abstract 'description' property i have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an abstract property that you don't intend to map to the database you might want to add an Ignore to that property in your automapping override.

```
 mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.Description);
```

Comment: yes , that was an abstract property and i marked it with a non persistent attribute to ignore it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [FluentNHibernate code that throws this exception](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/MappingModel/MappedMembers.cs#L89) suggests that you might be calling Map(x => x.Description) twice in your class map.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but when i checked the Map class i found out for some reason the code generator has put two instance of the same property as a result in run time this exception was thrown.

As a check list please check your Map file of the entity map class and make sure the mapping is unique to property.

I was able run it once i removed the duplicate one.

thanks